# snap don't see folders in /mnt

Tags: snap

After installing VLC player through

```
sudo snap install vlc --devmode
```

I start application and want to go and watch some movie that is on my NAS device and mounted as samba share at */mnt/DATA* folder.
But in open file dialog box */mnt* folder is empty.
I thought specifying *--devmode* enough to disable all snaps confinement.
Is there some additional configuration necessary for snaps to have access to host machine directories?

```
System:    Host: DzirT-LT Kernel: 4.13.0-32-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.12.1
           Distro: neon 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: Dell (portable) product: XPS 15 9550
           Mobo: Dell model: 0Y9N5X v: A07 Bios: Dell v: 1.6.1 date: 12/11/2017
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-6700HQ (-HT-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 2600 MHz 1: 2600 MHz 2: 2600 MHz 3: 2600 MHz 4: 2600 MHz 5: 2600 MHz 6: 2600 MHz
           7: 2600 MHz 8: 2600 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Skylake Integrated Graphics
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.5 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@59.93hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.8
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-H HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel Sound: ALSA v: k4.13.0-32-generic
Network:   Card: Broadcom BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC driver: brcmfmac
           IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: 44:1c:a8:e2:f2:03
Drives:    HDD Total Size: NA (-) ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 model: N/A size: 512.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 39G used: 13G (36%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 32.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 262 Uptime: 22 min Memory: 2091.7/15888.1MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.35
```

I see a lot of users marked my question as duplicate. I think it is not. So could someone explain me following, isn't specifying *--devmode* during install means remove all confinements from snap and have unlimited privileges? If I'm wrong in my expectation that it is duplicate, if not it is different case as in duplicated thread.

Comment: So, isn't specifying *--devmode* during install means remove all confinements  from snap and have unlimited privileges? I guess this question is little bit different from https://askubuntu.com/questions/964377/snap-application-doesnt-see-files-from-another-partition.

Comment: Did you find any workarounds? Thx.

Comment: Try to make symbolic link in you home folder and use it. This worked for me but I don't like such way of handling it. I guess --devmode should allow us to use any mounted folder but it seems not a case for me.