# File Dialog box does not see symbolic links

Tags: symbolic-link

I have my "Documents" folder linked to a directory on a different hard drive.

Freemind cannot see/access/or follow the link from its file open/save dialog boxes. If I filter the dialog box on "all files", the link(directory) shows up as a file, but it is not accessible. I even tried manually typing the path, but I get an error that the attempt to save failed.

On the other hand, that link works just fine with with Freeplane. It is visible and saving, opening, navigating, etc. all function normally.

Glancing over this, it would seem like a software(Freemind) problem, but I am almost positive I have seen something like this before as related to something else in the OS. I just cannot remember what it was related to and all the searches I have done have been useless because of the commonality of the key words.

Any thoughts???

ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Is `freemind` installed as a snap? If yes, you may have to configure permissions for this snap.

Comment: thanks... I was just in the midst of another test and I think you may be right. It looks like apparmor may be stopping it?

 May 14 01:05:45 juniper kernel: [86050.189845] audit: type=1400 audit(1557810345.343:86): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.freemind.freemind" name="/mnt/fromfailingdrive/" pid=28195 comm="java" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000

I am not terribly familiar with apparmor... i am assuming it serves the same function as SELinux?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure permissions is the problem now. Clearly I did not know anything about snaps, and after a couple of hours of reading about them I am not even sure I like the idea of them. But I learned some kindergarten manipulation of the snap interfaces/plugs/slots and realized I was not going to have any success. (at least, that is what I gather). It doesn't look like the one permission that I desire, can be allowed without basically opening all of the permissions.

Then I found this:

[Snap application doesn't see files from another partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964377/snap-application-doesnt-see-files-from-another-partition)

It provided an explanation I could understand.

I will just use freeplane instead.

Thanks for the direction @mook765.