# Programs from snap do not work with ntfs-3g

Tags: mount, kubuntu, ntfs, snap, ntfs-3g

I have programs from `snap` - Telegram, Skype and some others.

And I have secondary `ntfs` hdd drive shared with Windows.

All programs from snap can not read files from ntfs - Telegram, Skype.

I know that my `Kubuntu` using `ntfs-3g` driver.

`ntfs` drive mounts with dolfin (or I can mount on startup with KDE settings GUI with the same result).

The same programs from other repositories works fine.

Can it be solved, and how?

**PS:** I tried the way [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964377/snap-application-doesnt-see-files-from-another-partition). It fixes problem with Telegram using

```
sudo snap connect telegram-desktop:removable-media
```

but the same does not work with skype.

```
sudo snap connect skype:removable-media
```

> error: snap "skype" has no plug named "removable-media"

Comment: Thanks. It fixes problem with Telegram using `sudo snap connect telegram-desktop:removable-media`, but the same does not work with skype.

Comment: Doesn't it help if you mount the NTFS-partition somewhere under your home-directory?

Comment: I think I will do so. I already think about it. But strange for me that this is no normal way compatible with native ubuntu mount to `media`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get access to USB-storage from the application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap) - the problem is with `removable-media` plug, you should ask Microsoft to add it to the snap, or simply install deb-version.

Comment: @N0rbert right... ask Microsoft, I'm sure they will be more than happy to oblige.  Also, this problem isn't limited to just Skype, some snaps don't have a corresponding deb-version.