# Permission for snap arduino applications and Error opening serial port '/dev/ttyACM0' for other arduino application

Tags: usb, permissions, snap

i have installed two Arduino IDE in my Ubuntu one have installed form software application which have problem of accessing to mountable derives of my PC and by [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964377/snap-application-doesnt-see-files-from-another-partition) quid it don't solved:

```
sudo snap connect arduino:removable-media
```

this error:

```
so@so-notebook:~$ sudo snap connect arduino:removable-media
error: snap "arduino" has no plug named "removable-media"
```

and another by downloading the application file from Arduino website, which have problem in connecting to usb port  like this:

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Linux), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"

Error opening serial port '/dev/ttyACM0'. Try consulting the documentation at http://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/All#Permission
```

this problem solved by these codes of this instructions:

```
[sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER][2]

[sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0][2]
```

but in this situation one of my Arduino application can connect to hardware by USB port, but can not connect to mountable drives like this:

[image]

and another is vis versa.
like this:

[image]

so how can fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest Arduino IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025753/how-to-install-latest-arduino-ide)

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the Arduino snap since 17/07/2020. After installing the Arduino Snap, it should have access to removable media by default.