# VLC player cannot open files or directories out of "/home"

Tags: mount, directory, vlc

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with VLC player 3.0.11.

The player works well on files and directories within `/home` (for both `/home/myname` and `/home/test`), but cannot open files or directories located in other directories.

Some information about my environment:

Main output of `mount`:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda3 on /work type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda2 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

I try to add the following two lines in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince` and reload `apparmor`, but it doesn't work:

```
/work/ r,
/work/** rw,
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you using VLC's snap package?

Comment: Yes, output of "snap list |grep vlc": "vlc                      3.0.11                      1700  latest/stable    videolan*         -"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snap application doesn't see files from another partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964377/snap-application-doesnt-see-files-from-another-partition)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Snap packages are in containers which prevent them from "seeing" outside of those containers unless you give them permission.

For VLC, I'd recommend uninstalling the Snap package, and using the vanilla APT version:

```
sudo snap remove vlc

sudo apt update && sudo apt install vlc
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've reinstall it via apt, it works now.

Comment: Good stuff. Enjoy. 

Comment: Worked for me! Learn something every day; thx.

Comment: Thanks, had the same issue. Working after uninstall snap vlc and installing again using apt.
My problem was i have two disks in the PC, the one is a 4TB disk on /backup, i couldn't even see it if i opened VLC and selected "Open Directory"

Answer (score 6):

Snap applications can't guarantee the access of directories/files outside of current user's `$HOME`. From [zyga's](https://forum.snapcraft.io/u/zyga) [post](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/limitations-in-snapd/9718):

> - The `$HOME` directory of the user must match `/home/*`. Other directories are not supported yet. In particular `/home/subdir/user` is also not supported.
> - any installation where the user’s home is not available if they're not logged in, is not yet supported. This includes:
>
>   - installations using `automount`
>   - ecryptfs and similar tech that unencrypt the $HOME directory (or partition) only while the user is logged in
>
> Note here “not supported” does not mean “doesn’t work”. Some things might not work, but also some sequences of events might result in a user not being able to access their data.

So, it's better to switch to deb version of VLC provided by Ubuntu's official repositories. To install VLC, run

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends vlc
```

And remove VLC's snap package using

```
sudo snap remove vlc
```

Comment: Thank you for your detail explanation, I've reinstall it via apt and it works well now.

Comment: @robert Great!!

Comment: Sorry, seems I can only accept one answer as final answer, I select "mark smith" because he answered earlier. Both of your answers are useful for me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Access can be given with `snap connect`:

```bash
snap connect some-snap-name:removable-media
```

The name `removable-media` can be misleading, but that [how](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034065/229365) [it](https://askubuntu.com/a/964403/229365) [works](https://askubuntu.com/a/1184374/229365).