# snap install vlc seems to be faulty (Ubuntu 23.10)

Tags: apt, snap, vlc

Got a new notebook a month ago. Installed Ubuntu. Installed vlc with:

```
sudo snap install vlc
```

It made itself the default player for .wav files. Tried to play one I just generated. Could not open file. Went to check on a regular .avi file. It also could not find it. Tried to open the files manually from vlc menu and it could not even see my mounted directories.

Copied a file to /tmp. It still could not open them

```
sudo snap remove vlc
sudo apt install vlc
```

And all is good. VLC can now see my mounted drives and play anything.
Is snap known for installing VLC badly?

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/964403/590937) should give you a clue.

Comment: That does indeed explain why. Thanks. Sort of seems you should only use "snap install" for apps that can be confined. VLC is obviously not a candidate it it's sandboxed from removable drives where you might have movies, mountable devices etc. I guess it couldn't see all its decoders

Comment: The vlc snap should have the removable-media plug which then should be connected to the removable-media slot like in the linked answer. By default, snaps have access only to your home directory. The snap store should provide a permission tab which gives you the possibility to configure the permissions of a snap.